# AWS How Do I Trigger A Function On AWS Events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

Currently I am working to build a data structure ( Python Dictionary stored in mongo) which stores information of vpc's, subnet's and ec2 Instances. I want the data structure to be updated on real time basis whenever some activity which I want to tap into has took place 
eg:If a ec2 Instance is added or Deleted or Some Properties of the ec2 Instance is changed or if a new EBS Volume is attached to ec2 Instance etc

Comment: This sounds extremely similar to what [AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/index.html#lang/en_us) already offers. You might want to explore that service rather than trying to build it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

you can use CloudWatch a service provided by Amazon to watch all your infrastructure,
see [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html)

for more advanced events you can use CloudTrail
here is a [use case](https://blog.powerupcloud.com/capture-ec2-launch-termination-events-using-cloudtrail-cloudwatch-lambda-570461d9942a)

Comment: Can I also generate a event for A new Ec2 Instance being launched? also If a subnet is being added or deleted  same for vpc?